# Task Status WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following function :

```
async public Task<bool> checkNetwork (RestClient _client, ConnectivityManager conn)
    {
        var connected = false;
        var activeConn = conn.ActiveNetworkInfo;
        if (activeConn != null && activeConn.IsConnected) {
            var request = new RestRequest ();
            request.Timeout = 5000;
            var response = await _client.ExecuteAwait (request);
            //Task<IRestResponse> tmpResponse = _client.ExecuteAsync (request);
            if (response.ErrorException != null)
                connected = false;
            else
                connected = true;
        }

        return connected;
    }
```

It keeps hanging because the status never leaves WaitingForActivation when I call it.  Any ideas?

Comment: I assume `ExecuteAwait` is a custom method you wrote. Can you show the methods code?

Answer (score 15):

> It keeps hanging because the status never leaves WaitingForActivation when I call it.

Actually, the `WaitingForActivation` is just an indication that the task has not yet completed. It's not the cause of the hang, but an indicator of it. Promise Tasks (including tasks returned by `async` methods) will stay in the `WaitingForActivation` state until they complete; I describe the task state machine in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html).

The most likely cause of a deadlock is calling `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` further up the stack. I describe this deadlock in full [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but the gist of it is that `await` will capture a "current context" and use that to resume its `async` method. If called from the UI thread, then that context is the UI thread, and if the UI thread is blocked by calling `Result`/`Wait`, then the `async` method cannot resume on that UI thread.